# JQuery .ajax() function call not working, but success method runs

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm having trouble getting an ajax call to work on a webpage. The WebMethod works just fine.

One potential problem that I might see is that the code that calls the ajax method is located in a UserControl that is embedded in a content page that lives in a master page. This page can only be accessed after .Net authentication is verified. I have no clue if any of this matter, I'm just including this information so there are no hidden aspects of this issue.

Another potential issue may be in the Ajax call itself. I just can't see what the problem is. Most confusing of all, the success method in the ajax call runs.. there is no failure. More confusing, if I change the name of the WebMethod to something else entirely, the success method of the ajax call still runs.

Any idea what may be going wrong here?

```
var sendingThis = { x: 'abc', y: 'def', z: 'ghi' }

$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: "TestPage.aspx/someMethod",
    data: sendingThis,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    success: function (msg)
    {
         //THIS STUFF GETS CALLED...always
    },//end success

    error: function () 
    { 
      //DOESN'T GET CALLED 
    }
});
```

Codebehind method in TestPage.aspx:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void someMethod(string x, string y, string z) 
{
    //CODE THAT UPDATES DATABASE; *INDEPENDENTLY CONFIRMED WORKING* 
}
```

The button that calls the code..:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSomeMethod" runat="server" OnClientClick="return someMethod(this);" Text="Runit" />
```

Some additional observations I have that may help or not. I've tried using `ResolveURL` with the .ajax() call's URL, didn't work. I've also tried `EnableSession:true` as an attribute for the Web Method. I've tried inserting a `ScriptManager` into the page with `EnablePageMethods="true"` and a `ScriptReference` to the .js file that holds the Ajax() call. No luck whatsoever. What on earth is going on?

Another update: I checked the HTTP stream to see what the Response Header is from the the POST request. First off, it's returning 200 OK as the POST status code. Request seems all good. However, in the response header, I'm getting:

```
`"status":401,"headers":`
```

This is related to an authentication error.

Comment: check the status of the ajax request using the network tab of your browser's developer tool to see whether it is returning a 20x

Comment: @ArunPJohny GET or POST? I viewed it with FireBug and took a look at the POST request.. everything seemed fine.

Comment: did you tried without the quotes on the data: `{ x : "abc", y : "xyz", z : "qwe" }` ? because you have an extra quote on there

Comment: yeah, i tried removing them; i could have been incorrect on my reproduction here, but the original line looks like:

Comment: without the extra quote the ajax call seems fine to me, how do you know that the $.ajax is not working ?

Comment: fix a breakpoint inside your server side function and look its getting fired

Comment: i think Your data passing section has some error, check it

Comment: @user111222333 your url method name and method in server side are not matching please check my updated answer

Comment: @user111222333 Please don't use language like that on this site. I would flag your comment for deletion, but it contains content that is relevant to this discussion.

Comment: The TestPage. aspx file is a Content Page within a Master Page.. could this be a problem? I've tried everything here..  strangely enough  if I change the name of the Web Method, say, I introduce a typo, the JQuery call still runs the success method.

Comment: @SantiagoHernández I know the whole function is not working because I check my database for the uploaded data and it isn't there.

Comment: @SantiagoHernández Whereas if I independently invoke the web method, the data is indeed posted to the database. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV Yes, this was just in the example above. The development code is correct, but thanks for noting that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer came down to two forward slashes `//`.. In `RouteConfig.cs`, you need to comment out the line:

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
```

That's it, that's all.